# Javascript checkAll function

Tags: javascript

Running 1st snippet, the number of checkboxes in the `<td>` will be displayed in the alert box by clicking the checkbox of table header. However, running the 2nd snippet, the number of the checkboxs in the `<td>` will not be displayed in the alert box.

NOTE: 1st snippet get three table rows and 2nd snippet get two table row.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

**-------------1st Snippet--------------------**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckAll(formName,eleName,controlID)
        {
            var count = document.forms[formName].elements[eleName].length;
            alert(count);
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="report" method="post" action="#">

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">
                <input type='checkbox' id="selectController" onClick="CheckAll('report','list[]',this.id)"/>
                </th>
                <th width="30%">
                Name
                </th>
                <th width="30%">
                Number
                </th>
                <th width="35%">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id='row0' class='odd' >
                <td >
                <input name='list[]' type='checkbox'  value="1" id='checkbox-1' onClick='ClickCheckbox(this.id)' />
                </td>
                <td>
                SensorA
                </td>
                <td>
                1234567
                </td>
                <td>
                    [ <a href="#" class="basketlink">Add</a> ]
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='row1' class='even' >
                <td >
                <input name='list[]' type='checkbox'  value="2" id='checkbox-2' onClick='ClickCheckbox(this.id)' />
                </td>
                <td>
                SensorA
                </td>
                <td>
                1234567
                </td>
                <td>
                    [ <a href="#" class="basketlink">Add</a> ]
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**-----------2nd Snippet--------------**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckAll(formName,eleName,controlID)
    {
        var count = document.forms[formName].elements[eleName].length;
        alert(count);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="report" method="post" action="#">

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">
            <input type='checkbox' id="selectController" onClick="CheckAll('report','list[]',this.id)"/>
            </th>
            <th width="30%">
            Name
            </th>
            <th width="30%">
            Number
            </th>
            <th width="35%">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id='row0' class='odd' >
            <td >
            <input name='list[]' type='checkbox'  value="1" id='checkbox-1' onClick='ClickCheckbox(this.id)' />
            </td>
            <td>
            SensorA
            </td>
            <td>
            1234567
            </td>
            <td>
                [ <a href="#" class="basketlink">Add</a> ]
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On a side note, you have a `<td>` closed with `</th>` in your first example.

Comment: yes 1st one has three input tags and 2nd has only two. you are counting elements of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the ".length". length is a property of an array and not every javascript object. In your 2nd snippet, since you only have 1 checkbox what you are getting back by document.forms[formName].elements[eleName] is an object and not an array; this object does not have a length property. Hence you should do something like this:

```
    var count;
if(document.forms[formName].elements[eleName].length)
 count = document.forms[formName].elements[eleName].length;
else
 count = 1 //only if you are sure that you will always have 1 checkbox rendered, otherwise use some other logic to say 0 or 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second case there is only one. As a result, you don't get a `NodeList` (kind of Array), but rather the element itself, which does not have a `.length` property. So in case `.length === undefined`, assume it is `1`.

Narrowed down example:

- With 1 element: http://jsfiddle.net/9J4fB/1/
- With 2 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/9J4fB/